# segmentation fault while using custom sorting function to sort strings in a vector<string>

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, stdvector

I am trying to sort a vector that contains strings.  I have the following code for the main function

```
int size;
cin >> size;
vector<string> s;
cout << "READ" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    s.push_back(str);
}
cout << "READ" << endl;

cout << "Passed" << endl;
sort(s.begin(), s.end(), comp);

for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{
    string st = s.at(I);
    cout << st << endl;
}


return 0;
```

And the comp function code is

```
bool comp(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1.empty() or s2.empty())
        return false;

    int l = s1.length();
    for (int i = 0; i<l; i++)
    {
        if (s1[i] > s2[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But for this input I am getting a segmentation fault

```
46
lnpxeemwlqlzpxrmrmwbseqfnpkzaafdnukixaopcfvhqw
dhfhhoyhhzleldljmirjbqagcleivzomlpanqzsmqnrzij
zcsrvgqlmrgknqhwtcqzyldjanlczysnspvusziqtazjlu
idiknfqdygrwhvdzperlvgueqhuezsrwzztlodqgipnqzb
zjfyxbghvdecpzhvoxzojcpciaspyoeaetimmoccjqxtmv
mxwnhdyjutecwbrxdjmrbdjvbzprgnekvnvhxnuvekoflo
jjbjxzuaafatzdwlnzcorkiagrwzvrmjqqbdlmgyewzsea
bmvyqojhnbfrypiiwvtgifmqqdcuilohbfvkqjhlcwsfyo
zrbjhsrxnllmsdfqurkjfomwsvgfepwttohojxmrhexpmy
hcdxtucpeptgqhckpdxdcgpvhkiuucvwbuhtmbskqdlasw
rtocxkyrsrbluwvpfkekqkdwncvozfgmcrswpksiqmfnnl
xawlpinqjstxvrqvsugbvszhibbcmbdwktgwjlezakyqrr
cfghwolkahdafrcuufklziipmtkhuxdrxqlavcrxavxuas
plcsutiemkgfunhpyeiuvxwjppzsopglcyhgidsyhjnutp
vyyrbmfyfwpcowlpytmkvsyrzgiausrulsxtwysjgpgtqi
bsoknggdytplubxzjczatotnpovriwibeamjfnyxibvama
imkshtavbjpnkafuxwbzpiqlnnotrxmjepzeuwtuewtqab
ttjzqrcdcofkljaevmauexsxlkrxuanxgrsmsrxckixpoz
aocndkatjggduuyiksgmovthyoomrfsaxlnjouszxxoqtc
ahmkgizkvsbrqyricbtnpvpnibvgvnnrnqphkstvcjsbli
biasqbcofwdgabnipodjkriiyqlhaddpegkmydutcyoksk
avyaodwtgbdsnhheoearlinfcadeteiiudobbvqdqizcry
mhdekyvubghealrenyshjcjuhxxzimsgvukcdfdbjramzq
ayrzjanrebdgowsngullkgyvlgqzjexebleigxvgwjnbyf
vcpnclkhoawabjlhfnrncxfswjjmpxqcwoeqpyaitwdrjf
ghngenuvshwuaubahlzazwmgnsmtzyqfvvoxnhiufhxpac
ljrwslmgjilvdommuvpebcznjalxuazyujtzpewdbxjnwj
jqirnjnheowbioheyleyhkrcyfxuweyipumfojetmvomuz
vnnlsozyplofqkxfwcmlyntfrhspvbscocodlejqrymdeu
lgjcimksyragrhhagkmlnaysfxzswxfkhqzrhjlgkemmhp
weoxhopddcyiiikwblqvvcxcuxkebhywdacpmjrlkosxmw
bwcxxsytqdpybjxyqgmggitkgpkiytnwprsnxrygryxigo
qtwyleqxqflmaudekmdmgscfvjfwkchacxmokxrcfgwnhl
dgcmvhgnzigmrxougsbhwdhugyvloaqlliybbzkttmolln
jqmrfoyhwxbiyvzntvxozfswwjbeybahggfjrrzzhbapyi
oxbjadgrttqnfbevqolflhdpmgwgudhwfeebauqhhygvnt
kwmqirrljycddqcvjanibiarpcjjqiuvkdbdyzogbcixah
yyykebcfsnixcjdbkxtqvqynafmtuvoepeayiaqinvmjen
lsyxwgpfxlfkxckzsjzonxkhullkatmnwwfuicgjzbnvzf
vihglfapunknuitwtcxzdwjyfwqurvsydacylgcyohrbou
olmojrovoqseuqausssdupqzhbmyblomlbbqzwgbtgyiwq
tcshhbdgxsrtxywgqahqfimbnckwdhtbzlpwevuqjyqrbd
vjmcknagopzpwrmrianbgyhyginqduwdfjgmdqttcqroof
srmfsjigydlqlgsmvgqddpqmqkjzptzwdfpjmpnvgaezlx
yphbhtrmqcnrfklqmkblvginnhxxtlnnwcfuwujdqwkvaq
jahvrihhicrqvttmdzwbemjjqnstvtudvifdvrbjxalirj
```

For a lot other inputs it gives correct result but for the above result I get this result

```
READ
READ
Passed
```

I have searched a lot but cannot find the error in my `comp` function.

Comment: Why are you not just using [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater)?

Comment: actually i didnot know about it...i will surely try it

Comment: The problem is that you do not use the length of s2 in the comparison function

Comment: the constraint of the input is that each string has to be of same length

Comment: Also 2 empty strings should compare equal, but your comparison function says they are not.

Comment: Also, your comparison is flawed. Inside the `for` loop, you should also `return false` if `s1[i] < s2[i]`. And please pass the arguments to `comp` by *constant reference*, for all the gods' sake!

Comment: Then add a test that versifies that the lengths are the same.  Without that a mistake in the input will result in an unhandled error.

Comment: that was a constraint as well as the strings in input cannot be empty...can u plz edit and add the use of std::greater

Comment: Your comparison returns `true` for all pairwise comparisons between those strings, so each one is "smaller" than all the other ones.

Comment: yups the problem statement said that if any of the characters in above row are greater that the corrosponding character in the row below...they swap

Comment: You would probably break out of your input loop when `std::cin >> str;` fails. Then, can you be sure that your input strings don't contain whitespace characters?

Comment: it was a constraint as well?...any better idea that std::sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have noted, your comparison function is/was broken.

Here's an example that uses `std::greater<std::string>()` as a comparison function:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int size;
    if (!(std::cin >> size)) return -1;

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        std::string str;
        if (!(std::cin >> str)) return -1;
        v.push_back(str);
    }

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::greater<std::string>());

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is sorted in descending order (test.txt containing above input):

```
$ g++ test.cc && ./a.out < test.txt
zrbjhsrxnllmsdfqurkjfomwsvgfepwttohojxmrhexpmy
zjfyxbghvdecpzhvoxzojcpciaspyoeaetimmoccjqxtmv
zcsrvgqlmrgknqhwtcqzyldjanlczysnspvusziqtazjlu
yyykebcfsnixcjdbkxtqvqynafmtuvoepeayiaqinvmjen
yphbhtrmqcnrfklqmkblvginnhxxtlnnwcfuwujdqwkvaq
xawlpinqjstxvrqvsugbvszhibbcmbdwktgwjlezakyqrr
weoxhopddcyiiikwblqvvcxcuxkebhywdacpmjrlkosxmw
vyyrbmfyfwpcowlpytmkvsyrzgiausrulsxtwysjgpgtqi
vnnlsozyplofqkxfwcmlyntfrhspvbscocodlejqrymdeu
vjmcknagopzpwrmrianbgyhyginqduwdfjgmdqttcqroof
vihglfapunknuitwtcxzdwjyfwqurvsydacylgcyohrbou
vcpnclkhoawabjlhfnrncxfswjjmpxqcwoeqpyaitwdrjf
ttjzqrcdcofkljaevmauexsxlkrxuanxgrsmsrxckixpoz
tcshhbdgxsrtxywgqahqfimbnckwdhtbzlpwevuqjyqrbd
srmfsjigydlqlgsmvgqddpqmqkjzptzwdfpjmpnvgaezlx
rtocxkyrsrbluwvpfkekqkdwncvozfgmcrswpksiqmfnnl
qtwyleqxqflmaudekmdmgscfvjfwkchacxmokxrcfgwnhl
plcsutiemkgfunhpyeiuvxwjppzsopglcyhgidsyhjnutp
oxbjadgrttqnfbevqolflhdpmgwgudhwfeebauqhhygvnt
olmojrovoqseuqausssdupqzhbmyblomlbbqzwgbtgyiwq
mxwnhdyjutecwbrxdjmrbdjvbzprgnekvnvhxnuvekoflo
mhdekyvubghealrenyshjcjuhxxzimsgvukcdfdbjramzq
lsyxwgpfxlfkxckzsjzonxkhullkatmnwwfuicgjzbnvzf
lnpxeemwlqlzpxrmrmwbseqfnpkzaafdnukixaopcfvhqw
ljrwslmgjilvdommuvpebcznjalxuazyujtzpewdbxjnwj
lgjcimksyragrhhagkmlnaysfxzswxfkhqzrhjlgkemmhp
kwmqirrljycddqcvjanibiarpcjjqiuvkdbdyzogbcixah
jqmrfoyhwxbiyvzntvxozfswwjbeybahggfjrrzzhbapyi
jqirnjnheowbioheyleyhkrcyfxuweyipumfojetmvomuz
jjbjxzuaafatzdwlnzcorkiagrwzvrmjqqbdlmgyewzsea
jahvrihhicrqvttmdzwbemjjqnstvtudvifdvrbjxalirj
imkshtavbjpnkafuxwbzpiqlnnotrxmjepzeuwtuewtqab
idiknfqdygrwhvdzperlvgueqhuezsrwzztlodqgipnqzb
hcdxtucpeptgqhckpdxdcgpvhkiuucvwbuhtmbskqdlasw
ghngenuvshwuaubahlzazwmgnsmtzyqfvvoxnhiufhxpac
dhfhhoyhhzleldljmirjbqagcleivzomlpanqzsmqnrzij
dgcmvhgnzigmrxougsbhwdhugyvloaqlliybbzkttmolln
cfghwolkahdafrcuufklziipmtkhuxdrxqlavcrxavxuas
bwcxxsytqdpybjxyqgmggitkgpkiytnwprsnxrygryxigo
bsoknggdytplubxzjczatotnpovriwibeamjfnyxibvama
bmvyqojhnbfrypiiwvtgifmqqdcuilohbfvkqjhlcwsfyo
biasqbcofwdgabnipodjkriiyqlhaddpegkmydutcyoksk
ayrzjanrebdgowsngullkgyvlgqzjexebleigxvgwjnbyf
avyaodwtgbdsnhheoearlinfcadeteiiudobbvqdqizcry
aocndkatjggduuyiksgmovthyoomrfsaxlnjouszxxoqtc
ahmkgizkvsbrqyricbtnpvpnibvgvnnrnqphkstvcjsbli
```

For reference:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less

Comment: yes using `std::greater` is the best way...thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

Your comp method is broken.

For those two strings "ac" and "ca", `comp("ac", "ca")` is true as is `comp("ac", "ca")`. Because you try next position when `s1[i] < s2[i]` when you should return immediately false.

And as you were said in comments, you should cope with strings of different length by use the length of the shorter to avoid errors for accessing past string length.

So you comp method should be:

```
bool comp(string s1,string s2)
{
    // empty string comes last
    if(s1.empty()) return false;
    if(s2.empty()) return true;

    // limit to shorter string length
    unsigned int l = s1.length();
    if (s2.length() < l) l = s2.length();
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        // if chars are different at position i return immediately
        if(s1[i] > s2[i])
            return true;        
        if(s1[i] < s2[i])
            return false;        
    }
    // shorter string comes last
    return(s1.length() >= s2.length());
}
```

Comment: no the lengths of the two strings have to be same...that was a constraint

Comment: and there was also a constraint that if the above string had a char which was greater that the character at the corrosponding index in the string below the two strings should swap

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

```
 if (s1.empty() or s2.empty())
    return false;
```

does not satisfy strict weak ordering requirement to comp function (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings)

> > If x < y, then for all z, either x < z or z < y or both.

In your case if `z` is empty string and `x` and `y` are not, it would not satisfy either `x < z` nor `z < y`

Possible implementation is:

```
if( s2.empty() ) return !s1.empty();
if( s1.empty() ) return false;
```

But I do not see why you cannot use either `std::greater` `std::string::compare` or `std::string::operator>()` instead of manual implementation

Comment: it would be great if u can give the updated code...then i can clear my concept of strict weak ordering

Comment: can u plz give me the complete code of the comp function that doesnot suffer from the segmentation fault for the above input...it would be great...